# Program only works when stepping through - LPCXpresso18S37

Tags: c, debugging, embedded, lpcxpresso

I am not very experienced in embedded systems and I need to develop a program on an LPCXpresso18S37 that is able to communicate with a Python script to send and receive data using UART and the DMA. I am using MCUXpresso IDE and LPCOpen library.

The communication is basically a series of byte exchanges, where the Python script sends commands, to which the MCU responds by performing specific actions.

For example : if the Python scripts sends command "1", the MCU will send it back as an ack, and then wait to receive 16-bytes of plaintext, which will be sent by the Python script, etc...

Here is my problem : when in debug mode and stepping through instructions, the program behaves as expected : bytes are received and sent properly, stored in designated memory.

However, whenever I run the program "full speed", without any breakpoints or without stepping instructions, things get weird and the programs starts behaving in a way I really can not understand : most of the data being sent or received seems to be lost.

I have spent a lot of time trying to debug or at least figure out what's going on, but, I admit, without great success...

I am using the DMA without interruptions, as a different buffer is fulled everytime.

I have seen that some similar problems have been encountered by some developers, but I wasn't able to translate the solutions to my situation.

I would gladly welcome any help or ideas. Thank you in advance.

Here is the code in question :

```
#if defined (__USE_LPCOPEN)
#if defined(NO_BOARD_LIB)
#include "chip.h"
#else
#include "board.h"
#endif
#endif

#include <cr_section_macros.h>

 

uint8_t dmaChannelNumTx, dmaChannelNumRx;

FunctionalState  isDMATx = ENABLE;

 

static void App_DMA_Init(void)
{
    /* Initialize GPDMA controller */
    Chip_GPDMA_Init(LPC_GPDMA);
}

 

static void App_DMA_DeInit(void)
{
    Chip_GPDMA_Stop(LPC_GPDMA, dmaChannelNumTx);
    Chip_GPDMA_Stop(LPC_GPDMA, dmaChannelNumRx);
}

 

//Send data via USART0 and DMA
void Send_DMA(uint8_t *data_array, uint32_t data_size, uint8_t dmaChannelNumTx)
{
    isDMATx = ENABLE;
    while(Chip_GPDMA_Transfer(LPC_GPDMA,
                        dmaChannelNumTx,
                        (uint32_t) data_array,
                        GPDMA_CONN_UART0_Tx,
                        GPDMA_TRANSFERTYPE_M2P_CONTROLLER_DMA, //Memory to peripheral
                        data_size) != SUCCESS) {}
}

 

void Receive_DMA(uint8_t *data_array, uint32_t data_size, uint8_t dmaChannelNumRx)
{
    isDMATx = DISABLE;
    while(Chip_GPDMA_Transfer(LPC_GPDMA,
                        dmaChannelNumRx,
                        GPDMA_CONN_UART0_Rx,
                        (uint32_t) data_array,
                        GPDMA_TRANSFERTYPE_P2M_CONTROLLER_DMA, //peripheral to memory
                        data_size) != SUCCESS) {}
}

 

int main(void) {

 

    #if defined (__USE_LPCOPEN)
    // Read clock settings and update SystemCoreClock variable
    SystemCoreClockUpdate();

 

    #if !defined(NO_BOARD_LIB)

 

    // Set up and initialize all required blocks and
    // functions related to the board hardware
    Board_Init();
    Board_UART_Init(LPC_USART0);

 

    //Initialise USART with 115200 baudrate, 8-bits length, no parity and 1-bit stop
    Chip_UART_Init(LPC_USART0);
    Chip_UART_SetBaud(LPC_USART0, 115200);
    Chip_UART_ConfigData(LPC_USART0, (UART_LCR_WLEN8 | UART_LCR_SBS_1BIT | UART_LCR_PARITY_DIS));
    Chip_UART_TXEnable(LPC_USART0);

    #endif

 

    #endif

 

    //Setting up communication using DMA
    Chip_UART_SetupFIFOS(LPC_USART0, (UART_FCR_FIFO_EN | UART_FCR_RX_RS |
                                UART_FCR_TX_RS | UART_FCR_DMAMODE_SEL | UART_FCR_TRG_LEV0));

 

    //=======================================================================//
    /* Init command, receiver and trasmitter buffers ------------------------*/
    //=======================================================================//
        uint8_t command[1];
        uint8_t RX_plaintext[16];
        uint8_t RX_key[16];
        uint8_t TX_ciphertext[16];
        command[0] = 0;
    //=======================================================================//


    while(1)
    {
        App_DMA_Init();
        dmaChannelNumTx = Chip_GPDMA_GetFreeChannel(LPC_GPDMA, GPDMA_CONN_UART0_Tx);
        dmaChannelNumRx = Chip_GPDMA_GetFreeChannel(LPC_GPDMA, GPDMA_CONN_UART0_Rx);

 

        //Receive and send back command
        Receive_DMA((uint8_t*) command, 1, dmaChannelNumRx);
        Send_DMA((uint8_t*) command, 1, dmaChannelNumTx);

 

           //Obey the command
        switch(command[0])
            {
                //Command to receive plaintext and send back first byte for ack
                case 1:
                    Receive_DMA((uint8_t*) RX_plaintext, 16, dmaChannelNumRx);
                    Send_DMA((uint8_t*) &RX_plaintext[0], 1, dmaChannelNumTx);
                    command[0] = 0;
                break;

 

                //Command to receive key and send back first byte for ack
                case 2:
                    Receive_DMA((uint8_t*) RX_key, 16, dmaChannelNumRx);
                    Send_DMA((uint8_t*) &RX_key[0], 1, dmaChannelNumTx);
                    command[0] = 0;
                break;

 

                //Command to XOR key and plaintext
                case 3:
                    for(int i = 0; i<16; i++)
                        TX_ciphertext[i] = RX_plaintext[i] ^ RX_key[i];
                    command[0] = 0;
                break;

 

                //Command to send ciphertext
                case 4:
                    Send_DMA((uint8_t*) TX_ciphertext, 16, dmaChannelNumTx);
                    command[0] = 0;
                break;
                default:
                    break;

 


            }

 

    }

 

    App_DMA_DeInit();
    Chip_UART_DeInit(LPC_USART0);

 

    return 0 ;
}
```

Comment: In debug mode how many iterations of while(1) you checked? What is the behavior if no free channels are available?

Answer (score 1):

It's gonna be hard to say exactly what's causing it, it sounds like a timing-related bug. The first thing to consider: did you get whatever you are trying to do working without DMA? And why are you using DMA if it's just 1 byte of data and your program isn't doing much other work?

Some potential problems spotted:

- Should you really init the DMA from inside the for-ever loop and not just once?
- Your DMA buffers aren't volatile qualified, which could lead to incorrect optimizations.
- Your DMA buffers are stack allocated, which is plain wrong. They need to be placed at static storage with a fixed address.
- I don't know this lib, but if there's a `Chip_UART_TXEnable`, shouldn't there be one for `RX` too? Or is that done by the FIFO function?
- Your various casts when calling your own functions are fishy. Why do you cast? If you find yourself in need of that, always suspect bugs.
- It's not a PC so `int main(void)` doesn't make any sense. You are returning what to whom? Nor does "cleaning up after the program is done" make any sense. Microcontroller programs don't end. If using gcc you should compile with `-ffreestanding` and use `void main (void)`.
- Watchdog? Where is it? Is it on, is it off, where do you feed it?